# Django Crispy forms and i18n in HTML Layout

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I tried searching but could not find any answer to this, in Django crispy forms there is an HTML layout Object which allows you to inject customized HTML into your form, I am working on a CreateView Form which implements some arbitary creation of related elements, I inject the HTML under my field the following way:

```
HTML(
'''<p class="add">
      <a href="{% url 'manager-add-category' %}">{% trans 'Add a category' %}</a>
   </p>'''
),
```

My problem is that although url tags work ok, trans tags are not parsed within crispy forms, is there an alternative (maybe within crispy forms?) to maintain i18n?
In the form template there is proper i18n loading of tags:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to do it in some .py file (as i understood), then why do you bother with templatetags - use python.

```
injected_html = u"<p class='add'><a href='%(url)s'>%(translation)s</a></p>" % {'url':some_get_url_method(), 'translation':_(u"Add a category")}

HTML(injected_html)
```

Comment: Didn't think about it, gonna check it and get back! Thanks!

Comment: If this line gives you error regarding translations or you see proxy object in string instead of translated text, then change ugettext_lazy (_) method for ugettext. should work :P. I always mix these up...